# Update OperationContracts of WCF hosted in a windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wcf-hosting

I had a WCF hosted in a windows service. It worked fine. But I recently added a new web method to the WCF. But when I host the wcf in the same windows service, I can't access the newly added web methods, wsdl don't show newly added methods. Any Ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: How dou you "host wcf in the same windows service"?

Comment: You had a WCF? What kind of a WCF was it? A WCF client? A WCF Service? What?

Comment: WCF service library @Grzegorz Actully I added the updated WCF service library .dll file to the existing windows service ( even you can consider it as a new windows service )

Comment: I assume You restarted your windows service? :D Post Your WCF service code.

Comment: This might be a stupid question - but you have added the OperationContract attribute to the new method?

Comment: Code is pretty simple. The problem is It didn't work after I added a new web method in WCF sevice library. I'm hosting it on a windows service.

Comment: I just recreated the windows service project, and wrote the code from the bigining .. now the problem solved but the daam method